# Making a constructor swift that relies on network (making UIImage from url)

Tags: swift

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/4166655, I found that I can create a `UIImage` with this code

```
func downloadImage(from url: URL) {
    print("Download Started")
    getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

I saw many `UIImageView` extensions incorporating this code, but I wondered if I could make this work as a direct init for `UIImage`.

I came up with this —

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(url: String) {
        guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else { return nil }
        self.init(url: urlObj)
    }

    convenience init?(url: URL) {
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        var imageData: Data? = nil

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            // breakpoint put here
            guard let data = data else { return }
            imageData = data
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()

        if let data = imageData {
            self.init(data: data)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

But this just times out, and my breakpoint (noted in the code) never triggers.

What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Waiting on a completion handler like this defeats the entire point of the completion handler: you're blocking the main thread, and freezing the UI, to wait for a web request to finish (which it may never do).

Comment: Fair point - at this point I'm just curious why this doesn't even work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my breakpoint (noted in the code) never triggers

Because you never actually started the URLSession data task (by telling it to `resume`):

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        // whatever
    }.resume() // <-- this is what's missing
```

However, your entire approach here is wrong:

- You cannot "pause" during an initializer and "wait" for some asynchronous operation to complete while blocking the main queue. You need to return the initialized instance right now.
- If this were not an initializer and were happening on a background queue, the best way to "wait" for another background operation to finish would be with a DispatchQueue.